# Why is Redis source connector not available for Flink?

Tags: redis, apache-flink, flink-streaming, redis-streams

We are looking to use existing redis streams in our application and process messages using Apache Flick, but could not find Redis source connector ? Any reason why Redis source connector is not available ? any constraint, is it technically not feasible ?

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Redis connector, which was moved to Apache Bahir because there was no demand by the users. That also meant that there were no maintainers or contributors for Redis. You can find the discussion on the Flink Dev mailing list at https://lists.apache.org/thread/7lxsl5s8wyjlfh1ygrznkw4pvdfn9hg5 and the (not maintained) code at https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/tree/master/flink-connector-redis

If there were users that wanted to have contribute and maintain a Redis connector, that most likely would be possible since all of Flink's connector are currently being externalized to its own repository.

Comment: Thank for you for information. Though surprised to see less demand for Redis connector, especially there is no Redis source connector till now.

Answer (score 1):

Update: there's a new Flink Redis Connector in the works, which should become available at https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-redis-streams